# How to define this typescript interface type

Tags: typescript

Hello StackOverflow community,

I would like to ask, how to properly define this type in Typescript, if possible.
I have been wondering if this could be achieved with Generics usage.
Assuming the key for the object will always be different and do not follow a normalised model.

`{ status_id: { original: "A", new: "B" } },`

Where status_id could be any field.

```
export interface IParsedLog {
  changes?: any; // How to properly define this Type in Typescript?
  date: Date;
}

const mock:IParsedLog[] = [
  {
    changes: [
         { status_id: { original: "A", new: "B" } },
         { any_field_id: { original: "A", new: "B" } },
    ],
    date: '10-06-2020',
  },
  {
    changes: [
         { supervisor_id: { original: "Jhon", new: "Jhony" } },
    ],
    date: '10-06-2020',
  }];
```

Comment: `status_id` and `any_field_id` come from another type ? Or ar just are they just random keys? Do you want to capture the info from the `mock` variable or is tha data coming in from somewhere else ? `Array<Record<string, { original:  string, new: string }>>` seems like the simplest type here ..

Comment: `status_id` or `any_field_id` are random keys. 
thanks for your answer, I think I found out the solution as posted bellow!

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface IChange {
  [key: string]: ({ original: string, new:string});
}

export interface IParsedLog {
  changes: IChange[], 
  date: Date;
}

const mock:IParsedLog[] = [
  {
    changes: [
         { status_id: { original: "A", new: "B" } },
         { any_field_id: { original: "A", new: "B" } },
    ],
    date: '10-06-2020',
  },
  {
    changes: [
         { supervisor_id: { original: "Jhon", new: "Jhony" } },
    ],
    date: '10-06-2020',
  }];
```